# Nginx - in try_files, php file downloaded instead of executed

Tags: php, nginx

If I request /maintenance.php, it gets executed.

If I request /foo (and maintenance.php exists), maintenance.php gets downloaded.

What am I missing ?

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /maintenance.php @rewriteapp;
}
location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_prod.php/$1 last;
}
location ~ ^/(app_prod|maintenance)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

NB: It seems like

```
location ~ ^/(app_prod|maintenance)\.php(/|$)
```

is not triggered after

```
try_files $uri /maintenance.php @rewriteapp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [explained here](https://serverfault.com/a/329970/235897), `try_files` itself will not issue an internal redirect for anything but the last parameter.

So, if maintenance.php exists,

```
try_files $uri /maintenance.php @rewriteapp;
```

will simply serve the file as plain text or download it depending on your `default_type` configuration setting.

### Solution

NB: According to the doc, it is [perfectly fine](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) to use if in this situation.

```
if (-f $document_root/maintenance.php) {
    return 503;
}
error_page 503 @maintenance;
location @maintenance {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php;
}
```

Actually, I wanted to show the logo in the maintenance page, so I ended up with a few extra lines to allow assets to be served.

```
if (-f $document_root/maintenance.php) {
    return 503;
}
error_page 503 @maintenance_or_assets;
location @maintenance_or_assets {
    try_files $uri @maintenance;
}
location @maintenance {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and look for a line that starts with "listen =".

Make sure it is set to "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock" and not 127.0.0.1:9000.

If it is set to the IP address change it and restart PHP.

Comment: It is already the case. /app_prod.php and /maintenance.php work just fine.

Comment: Try changing both to 127.0.0.1:9000 in the www.conf and virtual host file then restarting PHP.